# Jquery animated div margins appear to change depending on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

Problem: I have an animated div which is essentially a 2D rendering of a cube, with each face being a new page. However, whenever the page is resized (say on a mobile device or tablet or giant desktop) the left and right sides of the square change position in relation to the edges of the window, and are different with every turn of the "cube". Follow the link below, resize your screen to be smaller and try clicking on the menu items to see what I mean. The top and bottom remain constant, but the left and right are constantly moving off of true center.

Question: How do I get the "cube" face to remain centered no matter which menu item is clicked? Thank you for your help, time and patience!

website: http://studiopowell.net/tp.html
relevant code below:

```
        <style>
      .face {
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      width: 97%;
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color:rgba(20,20,20,.5);
      border: solid 1px #ccc;
      pointer-events: none;
    }


    #cube {
      position: relative;
      margin: 0 auto;
      height: 70%;
      width: 80%;
      -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transition: all 2s ease;
      pointer-events: none;
    }

    #cube .one {
      -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(200px);
      transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(200px);
    }

    #cube .two {
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(200px);
      transform: translateZ(200px);
    }

    #cube .three {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(200px);
      transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(200px);
    }

    #cube .four {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(200px);
      transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(200px);
    }
    #cube .five {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
      transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
    }

    #cube .six {
      -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(200px) rotate(180deg);
      transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(200px) rotate(180deg);
    }



    canvas {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        max-height: 100%;
        max-width:100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        min-width:100%;
    }




    </style>

    <canvas id="c"></canvas>
    <div class="menu"><div id="aboutlink">About</div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<div id="futurelink">Future</div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<div id="pastlink">Past</div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<div id="contactlink">Contact</div></div>
    <div class="text">TRANSVERSAL</br>PROJECT</div>
    <div id="cube">
    <div class="face one"></div>
    <div class="face two"></div>
    <div class="face three"></div>
    <div class="face four"></div>
    <div class="face five"></div>
    <div class="face six"></div>


    </div>



    <script src="http//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.16.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://dat-gui.googlecode.com/git/build/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#aboutlink").click(function(){
       calcRotation(0);
    });
    $("#futurelink").click(function(){
      calcRotation(90);
    });
    $("#pastlink").click(function(){
       calcRotation(180);
    });
    $("#contactlink").click(function(){
    calcRotation(270);
    });
    function calcRotation(rot){
       $("#cube").css("transform", "rotateY(-" + rot + "deg)");
    }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: trying defining min-width and max-width's

Comment: tried defining both for the #cube and for the .face, but no change in problem.